# Laplacian and Fourier transform

Tags: rotations, fourier-transform, laplacian

Show the laplacian is rotationally invariant:

$\Delta(f\circ R)=(\Delta f)\circ R, \forall R\in SO_d(\mathbb{R})$.

Suggestion:  You can use that the Fourier Transform (FT) of $f(Ax)$ is $det(A)^{-1}\hat{f}((A^{-1})^t\xi)$ (lineal composition) and that FT of $\Delta f(x)$ is $-4\pi^2|\xi|^2\hat{f}(\xi)$.

I'm completely lost. Pelase help

Comment: That is $\Delta$ is a radial distribution, which is clear from $\displaystyle\Delta f(x) = \lim_{r \to 0^+} 2\frac{f(x)-\frac{1}{C}\int_{|y| < 1} f(x+y/r)dy}{r^2}$ where $C=  \int_{|x| < 1} dx$

Comment: Or from $\widehat{\Delta}(\xi) = -4\pi^2 |\xi|^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Fourier transform of $f(Ax)$ is
$$
         \mathcal{F}\{f\circ A\}(\xi)=  \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(Ax)e^{-ix\cdot \xi}dx.
$$
Let $y=Ax$. Then $x=A^t y$ because $A^tA=AA^t=I$ by the definition of a symmetric orthogonal matrix. The Jacobian of this transformation is $|A^t|=1$, which gives
\begin{align}
    \mathcal{F}\{f\circ A\}(\xi) & = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(y)e^{-i(A^t y)\cdot \xi}dy \\
    & = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(y)e^{-iy\cdot(A\xi)}dy \\
    & = (\mathcal{F}\{ f\}\circ A)(\xi)\end{align}
In other words, $\mathcal{F}\{f\circ A\}=\mathcal{F}\{f\}\circ A$. Therefore,
\begin{align}
      -\Delta (f\circ A) &= \mathcal{F}^{-1}\{|\xi|^2\mathcal{F}\{f\circ A\}\} \\
   &= \mathcal{F}^{-1}\{ |A\xi|^2\mathcal{F}\{f\}\circ A\} \\
   &= \mathcal{F}^{-1}\{ |\xi|^2\mathcal{F}\{f\}\}\circ A \\
   &= (-\Delta f)\circ A.
\end{align}